# Can't connect nodejs to mysql by docker compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to run my server in NodeJS and a MySQL database using Docker , when I run `sudo docker-compose up` I get this error in nodejs server:

```
Access denied for user 'Pedro'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: YES)
backend_container |     at Packet.asError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
backend_container |     at ClientHandshake.execute (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
backend_container |     at Connection.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
backend_container |     at PacketParser.onPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
backend_container |     at PacketParser.executeStart (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
backend_container |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
backend_container |     at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
backend_container |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)
backend_container |     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)
backend_container |     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10) {
backend_container |   code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
backend_container |   errno: 1045,
backend_container |   sqlState: '28000',
backend_container |   sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'Pedro'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: YES)",
backend_container |   sql: undefined
backend_container | }
```

this is how I connect to the database in Nodejs:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
    user: process.env.DB_USER, 
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE, 
    timezone: 'Z'
});


db.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error al conectar a la base de datos:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Conexión exitosa a la base de datos!");
    }
});
```

this is my NodeJS dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    database:
      image: "mysql"
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpasswd
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Monitoreo
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./BD/Monitoreo_BD.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Monitoreo_BD.sql
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

    backend:
        image: 'pedrocastro2001/backend-so1'
        container_name: "backend_container"
        environment:
          DB_HOST: database
          DB_USER: Pedro
          DB_PASSWORD: Pedro22
          DB_DATABASE: Monitoreo
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
          - database

    frontend:
        image: 'pedrocastro2001/frontend-so1'
        container_name: "frontend_container"
        ports:
          - "5173:5173"

    

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Is there something wrong with my docker-compose file? how can I solve it? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's because you did not config the user `Pedro` in your `mysql` container.
Try adding those to the environment config of `mysql` container in your docker compose file

```
MYSQL_USER: Pedro
MYSQL_PASSWORD: Pedro22
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this environment for mysql container.

```
environment:
      MYSQL_USER: Pedro
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Pedro22
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpasswd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Monitoreo
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations for other that might come later?

Answer (score 0):

You can create .env file whit yours variables enviroments like this in your root repository:

```
MYSQL_USER: Pedro
MYSQL_PASSWORD: Pedro22
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpasswd
MYSQL_DATABASE: Monitoreo
```

Later you call this variable in your docker-compose.yml:

```
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
  - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

You must add to your docker-compose your db container:

```
db:
image: mysql:8.0 <- this is the last version
restart: always
expose:
  - "3306"
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
  - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
volumes:
  - db:/var/lib/mysql
```

If you can connect to database, in this case, mysql, you need create this container
This is in macOs